# How can i update blank TextBox to SQL in C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have one TextBox (Name:TB_Test)
If I do not input any string....
In SQL DB "test" field will get "NULL"
How can i do,"test" field change blank string ,not "NULL"
thank you

Michael Wu from Taiwan

Code :

```
SqlDataSource SqlDataSource1 = new SqlDataSource();
SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters.Clear();
SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters.Add("test",String.IsNullOrEmpty(TB_Test.Text.ToString()) ? "": TB_Test.Text.ToString());
SqlDataSource1.Update();
```

Comment: Just replace `"test"` with `"@test"` and `Add` with `AddWithValue`- rest of your code is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the DB as @Amit Kumar suggested or use the `Add(Parameter)` overload of `ParameterCollection`. Something like this:

```
var parameter = new Parameter("test")
{
  DefaultValue = String.IsNullOrEmpty(TB_Test.Text.ToString()) 
     ? "" : TB_Test.Text.ToString()),

  ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false
};
SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters.Add(parameter);
```

The important part is the `ConvertEmptyStringToNull` property of the `Parameter` class which defaults to true.

Answer (score 1):

Add default value to your Column.

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD CONSTRAINT DF_SomeName DEFAULT N'' FOR test;
```

Comment: Although I can set the default value "blank"
But after the update becomes NULL again

Answer (score 0):

try `String.Empty` as below.

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(TB_Test.Text.ToString()) ? String.Empty : TB_Test.Text.ToString()
```

Comment: Use "String.Empty" code,The result is the same "NULL"